# Getting segmentation fault when trying to reverse a string in NASM

Tags: string, segmentation-fault, nasm

I'm trying to write an assembly language in NASM where i do various operations on a string.
One of the operations that i'm doing is to the reverse string.
What i'm trying to do is to make rsi point to the end of the string and then copy its contents to another place which will be pointed by rdi.
The problem arises when i'm trying to move the contents pointed by rsi to the al register.

Here is the code:

```
section .data
    menu db "MENU",10
        db "--------------",10
        db "1.Accept String",10
        db "2.Reverse String",10
        db "3.Terminate",10
        db "--------------",10
        db "Enter your choice:",10
    menu_len equ $-menu

    msg1 db "Enter a string",10
    msg1_len equ $-msg1

    msg2 db "The reversed string is..",10
    msg2_len equ $-msg2

    msg3 db "Wrong Choice!",10
    msg3_len equ $-msg3

    newl db 10
    l equ $-newl

section .bss
    string1 resb 20
    string2 resb 20
    strlen resb 1
    strlen2 resb 1
    choice resb 2

    %macro disp 2
    mov rax,4
    mov rbx,1
    mov rcx,%1
    mov rdx,%2
    int 80h
    %endmacro

    %macro accept 2
    mov rax,3
    mov rbx,0
    mov rcx,%1
    mov rdx,%2
    int 80h
    %endmacro

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    disp menu,menu_len
    accept choice,2

    cmp byte[choice],'1'
    je case1
    cmp byte[choice],'2'
    je case2
    cmp byte[choice],'3'
    je exit
    disp msg3,msg3_len
    jmp _start

case1:
    disp msg1,msg1_len
    accept string1,20
    dec rax
    mov [strlen],rax
    jmp _start

case2:
    mov bl,byte[strlen]
    mov byte[strlen],bl
    mov rsi,string1
    add rsi,[strlen]
    dec rsi
    mov rdi,string2
    mov rcx,[strlen]
l1:
    mov al,[rsi]    ;<- Getting a segmentation fault here
    mov [rdi],al
    dec rsi
    inc rdi
    loop l1
    disp msg2,msg2_len
    disp string2,20
    disp newl,l
    jmp _start

exit:
    mov rax,1
    mov rbx,0
    int 80h
```

Comment: When you do things like `mov [strlen],rax` you are moving 8 bytes (64-bit) contents of the register into the destination. But `strlen` itself is only allocated as one byte. That one instruction wipes out the contents of strlen and the following 7 bytes in memory. It applies in reverse too `mov rcx,[strlen]` moves the 8 bytes starting at strlen and copies them into _RCX_. But `strlen` is only one byte so will pull in the values from the 7 bytes after strlen. So it is quite possible _RCX_ will have a much bigger value than you expect if there are values other than zero in the other 7 bytes after

Comment: Every case where you currently use `strlen` and a 64-bit register is an issue.

Comment: Although not part of your problem, you really should consider using 64-bit `syscall` instruction rather than 32-bit `int 80h` when developing x86-64  Linux code. There is reasonable information on that here: http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64

Comment: @Jester doesn't seem to be around to suggest that you may wish to learn to use a debugger. _GDB_ works well. You can step through assembly code, watch your register values, display memory etc.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Hey thanks for helping out! I replaced all the 64bit registers with 32bit and it worked!

Comment: Changing them to 32-bit is still a problem. EIther you access strlen as a byte, or you should allocate 8 bytes (a quadword) for `strlen` and `strlen2`. With something like `strlen resq 1` `strlen2 resq 1`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yep i used resq to allocate memory to strlen and changed the registers back to 64bit and it worked! Thanks a ton. I also tried my hands on the GDB debugger but every time I jumped to the next instruction using 'n' it told me: *Single stepping until exit from function _start,which has no line number information.*